# For two norms $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$ in the same space, the following statements equivalent

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to show that for two norms $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$ in the same space,  the following statements equivalent:

a) $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$ equivalent

b) Exist $m,M>0$ such that for all v we have that $m||v||_1 \le ||v||_2\le M||v||_1$

I know that two norms on a vector space are equivalent if the topologies induced by them are the same. So, in order to show that (b) implies (a) I have to show that $\tau_1=\tau_2$.

So let's suppose that exist $m,M>0$ such that for all $v$ we have that $m||v||_1 \le ||v||_2\le M||v||_1$. Let $U_1\in\tau_1$ and $v\in U_1$. As $U_1$ is open, $\exists\delta>0$ such that $B_1(v,\delta)\subseteq U_1$. In this way we have that $B_2(v,\delta m)\subseteq B_1(v,\delta)\subseteq U_1$. Therefore, $U_1\subseteq \tau_2$. Analogously let $U_2\in \tau_2$ and $v\in U_2$. As $U_2$ is open, then there exists $\delta>0$. such that $B_2(v,\delta)\subseteq U_2$. In this way we have that $B_1(v,\frac{\delta}{M})\subseteq B_2(v,\delta)\subseteq U_2$. Therefore, $U_2\subseteq \tau_1$. And then we have that $\tau_1=\tau_2$. And therefore $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$ equivalent.

But how can I prove that (a) implies (b)?

Comment: Assume (a) is true for a given space and suppose (b) is false. Then can you construct a sequence of vectors which converge to 0 wrt one of the norms but not the other?

Comment: @rikhavshah I still not sure how I can construct such sequence

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Equivalence

Comment: b) is just the continuity of the identity map from $(X,\|.\|_1)$ to $(X,\|.\|_2)$ and the continuity of the identity map from $(X,\|.\|_2)$ to $(X,\|.\|_1)$.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate. It is also easily available in books.

Comment: @Raven If (b) is false, then it is not the case that $\|v\|_2/\|v\|_1$ is lower bounded by any fixed constant $m$. In other words, there exists a sequence of vectors taking it to 0.